# Reading CSV Files using Fast CsvReader without quotes around fields

Tags: c#, parsing, csv, lumenworks

I'm having some issues using [Lumenworks Fast CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader). Using the code:

```
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(fileName)), true))
{
     csv.ParseError += csv_ParseError;

     while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
     {
          var importItem = new ProductImportItem(csv);
          if (!ProductsDALC.SearchByPartProductCode(importItem.ProductCode).Any())
          {
              if (!SaveProduct(importItem))
              {
                  this.ParseErrors.Add(string.Format("Failed to add product-{0}", importItem.ProductCode));
              }
          }
     }
}
```

The code works fine when the CSV file is formatted using double quotes either side of the fields/column values e.g:

> "product_code", "product_name", "item_description", "sku", "postage_level_required", "cost_price", "retail_price_inc_vat"

However, if the columns look like this:

> product_code,product_name,item_description,sku,postage_level_required,cost_price,retail_price_inc_vat

Then the code behaves as if there is no data, that is to say, it won't enter into the `while` loop and enumerating the result set in the debugger will show that it yields no results.

This would be fine if I had absolute control over the data in/out. However, all I can do is provide the user with a template which contains the fields and hope that they wrap the data in quotes. This isn't an acceptable approach.

Is there a way to get the reader to parse data even if it isn't wrapped in quotes?

I'm aware of the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class built into .Net which handles this fine but since we're using `CsvReader` elsewhere in the projec it would be good to remain consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide the information that the fields aren't quoted in the constructor by using the  [unicode "null" character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character):

```
Char quotingCharacter = '\0';  // means none
Char escapeCharacter  = '\0';
Char commentCharacter = '\0';
Char delimiter = ',';
bool hasHeader = true;
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, hasHeader, delimiter, quotingCharacter, escapeCharacter, commentCharacter, ValueTrimmingOptions.All))
{
    // ...
}
```